# Just failed an audit, but answer is legit and comment below the answer doesn't apply

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16774038

So I just failed that and I don't agree with the verdict and it's reason. Despite what the comment below the answer says, the answer **does** answer the question. There is no need for code as it's obvious without code.

I don't see how the question could be answered differently.

Comment: @gnat in hindsight it's a duplicate and the answer is valid here as well. When I posted this though I was under the impression that this specific answer/audit was wrong/faulty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer merits deletion on the grounds of simply repeating what *multiple* other answer have said over a year before, adding nothing at all to the post.

You're correct that it doesn't merit deletion for the reason given in the comment on the post.

Also, this is a First Posts audit, not a VLQ audit.  Even if you don't think that the answer merits deletion, it most certainly merits editing at a minimum, and commenting on how to improve it if you think it's worth keeping.

Comment: Yeah, but that's kinda tough as an audit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I can't *possibly* imagine how you could see the audit and think that no action is needed.  The answer doesn't add anything over *multiple* other answers with the same information, and even if it was the only answer it would require editing, even if you don't think it should be deleted (I *do* think it merits deletion) then comments indicating how it could be improved would be merited, etc.  If this was a VLQ queue audit I may have a bit of sympathy, as is, I don't.

Comment: @Servy I didn't saw any other answers in the review screen. Guess I should have checked the question.

Comment: @Servy didn't notice it was a first post audit.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler The review queue tells you that the question is over a year old, and that there are multiple other answers.  That should be enough to you make you suspicious.

Comment: @Servy you must have a different view on the audit than we do.  The audit says there is a single other answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Pretty sure that while you're seeing it *as an audit* it will count the audit itself in those counts, but now that the audit is over, it's showing the actual answer count (given that this answer is deleted).  Just like how when viewing it now it shows the comments, the actual user id, the actual post score, etc., while when it's an actual audit all of that isn't shown.

Comment: @Servy you are completely right. I didn't notice the 'other answers' text until now. Turns out I did fail that audit for a reason, it's just a different reason than what the audit thinks. I should have clicked on the question and I should have at least written a comment. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: since FP review provides an option to vote up/down, another way to pass the audit was to downvote

Comment: @Servy ah yeah that's probably true for the audit presentation.  It's not my favorite audit because of how subtle it is, but it's legit.